# reduce complexity of class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, reportlab

I have written this code to generate pdf report , I have used **ReportLab** library everything was working good but I must reduce the complexity of my code  , so the idea here I want transform methods into functions and let them out of class,

this is my code :

```
def result_simulation(path, id_design):

class FooterCanvas(canvas.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []
        self.width, self.height = LETTER

    def showPage(self):
        self.pages.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    def save(self):
        page_count = len(self.pages)
        for page in self.pages:
            self.__dict__.update(page)
            if (self._pageNumber > 1):
                self.draw_canvas(page_count)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

    def draw_canvas(self, page_count):
        page = "Page %s of %s" % (self._pageNumber, page_count)
        x = 128
        self.saveState()
        self.setStrokeColorRGB(0, 0, 0)
        self.setLineWidth(0.5)
        self.drawImage("src/services/files_generation/optilight-solar.png",
                       self.width - inch * 8 - 5, self.height - 50, width=100, height=20,
                       preserveAspectRatio=True, mask='auto')

        self.line(30, 740, LETTER[0] - 50, 740)
        self.line(66, 78, LETTER[0] - 66, 78)
        self.setFont('Times-Roman', 10)
        self.drawString(LETTER[0] - x, 65, page)
        self.restoreState()



class PDFPSReporte:

    def __init__(self, path, id_design):
        self.path = path
        self.styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
        self.elements = []

        # colors
        self.color1 = Color((72.0/255), (74.0 /255), (163.0 / 255), 1)
        self.color2 = Color((11.0/255), (168.0 /255), (107.0 / 255), 1)

        self.func1(id_design)
        self.func2(id_design)
        self.func3(id_design)
        self.func4(id_design)
       
        # Build
        self.doc = SimpleDocTemplate(path, pagesize=LETTER)
        self.doc.multiBuild(self.elements, canvasmaker=FooterCanvas)
report = PDFPSReporte('result1.pdf', id_design)
```

the code were inspired from https://github.com/jurasec/python-reportlab-example
my question here if there is an idea how can I transform my methods func1,func2,func3,func4 into functions and integrated into classes or if I must instantiate my classes than add functions ? any help please , thanks for your time